# The multi-part identifier "C.C_CRNT_STAT_CD" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

This may be impossible to answer but I am hoping for the best. I am far from an expert and have taken over this query from my predecessor. I have researched this error AT LENGTH and I do understand what it means I just cannot figure out what I am missing.

I added ********* behind each of my changes from the original query. I am trying to add the field `C.C_CRNT_STAT_CD t`o the query below and received the

> error: Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: The multi-part
>   identifier "C.C_CRNT_STAT_CD" could not be bound.

I would greatly appreciate any help and thank you so much in advance.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  zSTANCSPED1.CSPED_LAST_NM,
  zSTANCSPED1.CSPED_FIRST_NM,
  zSTANCSPED1.CSPED_MIDDLE_NM,
  zSTANCSPED1.CSPED_SSN,
  zSTANCSPED1.CSPED_DOB,
  zSTANCSPED1.CSPED_STUDY_ID,
  zSTANCSPED1.CSPED_RA_DATE,
  zSTANCSPED1.P_CSE_EXTID,
  zSTANCSPED1.C_CASE_EXTID,
  zSTANCSPED1.CC_COURT_CASE_EXTID,
  SUP.S_ACTV_NM_CD,
  SUP.S_TYPE_CD,
  SUP.S_SUPR_LVL,
  C.C_CRNT_STAT_CD,******************
  CASE WHEN (SUP.S_STRT_TS LIKE '%1900%') OR  (SUP.S_STRT_TS LIKE '%1901%')
  THEN NULL
  ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, SUP.S_STRT_TS, 108)
  END AS 'S_STRT_TS',
  CASE WHEN (SUP.S_END_TS LIKE '%1900%') OR  (SUP.S_END_TS LIKE '%1901%')
  THEN NULL
  ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, SUP.S_END_TS, 108)
  END AS 'S_END_TS',
  SUP.S_SUPR_DESC

FROM
(SELECT * FROM zSTANCSPED
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PD.P_PRTCP_ID,PD.SSN_SOC_SECURE_NUM,PD.P_CSE_EXTID,
PD.BI_BIRTH_DT
FROM PARTICIPANT_DEMOGRAPHIC PD) PD
ON zSTANCSPED.CSPED_SSN = PD.SSN_SOC_SECURE_NUM
AND zSTANCSPED.CSPED_DOB = PD.BI_BIRTH_DT

LEFT JOIN (SELECT CP.CP_PRTCP_ID,CP.CP_CASE_ID,CP.CP_ROLE_CD
FROM CASE_PARTICIPANT CP
WHERE CP.CP_STAT_CD <> 'OBS') CP
ON CP.CP_PRTCP_ID = PD.P_PRTCP_ID

LEFT JOIN (SELECT C.MTH_YR,C.CAS_CASE_ACCT_SUM_ID,C.C_CASE_ID,C.C_CASE_EXTID,C.C_MNG_CNTY_FIPS_CD,C.C_CRNT_STAT_CD*************
FROM CASE_CAS C 
WHERE (C.C_CRNT_STAT_CD <> 'obs')) C
 ON CP.CP_CASE_ID = C.C_CASE_ID

LEFT JOIN (SELECT CCC.CCC_CASE_ID,CC.CC_COURT_CASE_EXTID,
LA.LA_FILE_DT,LA.SO_HLTH_INSURE_ORDR_CD, CC_COURT_CASE_ID,LA_COURT_CASE_ID,LA.LA_LEGL_ACTV_ID
         FROM CASE_COURT_CASE CCC
         JOIN COURT_CASE AS CC
         ON CC.CC_COURT_CASE_ID =
         CCC.CCC_COURT_CASE_ID
         JOIN LEGAL_ACTIVITY AS LA
         ON LA.LA_COURT_CASE_ID =
         CC.CC_COURT_CASE_ID AND LA.LA_LGL_ACTV_TYPE_CD = 'SUP'
         AND LA.LA_STAT_CD = 'ACT'
         ) AS LA
         ON LA.CCC_CASE_ID = C.C_CASE_ID ) zSTANCSPED1

JOIN SUPPRESSION SUP
ON zSTANCSPED1.CP_PRTCP_ID = SUP.S_PRTCP_ID


UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 
  zSTANCSPED1.CSPED_LAST_NM,
  zSTANCSPED1.CSPED_FIRST_NM,
  zSTANCSPED1.CSPED_MIDDLE_NM,
  zSTANCSPED1.CSPED_SSN,
  zSTANCSPED1.CSPED_DOB,
  zSTANCSPED1.CSPED_STUDY_ID,
  zSTANCSPED1.CSPED_RA_DATE,
  zSTANCSPED1.P_CSE_EXTID,
  zSTANCSPED1.C_CASE_EXTID,
  zSTANCSPED1.CC_COURT_CASE_EXTID,
  SUP.S_ACTV_NM_CD,
  SUP.S_TYPE_CD,
  SUP.S_SUPR_LVL,
  C.C_CRNT_STAT_CD,**************
  CASE WHEN (SUP.S_STRT_TS LIKE '%1900%') OR  (SUP.S_STRT_TS LIKE '%1901%')
  THEN NULL
  ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, SUP.S_STRT_TS, 108)
  END AS 'S_STRT_TS',
  SUP.S_END_TS,
  SUP.S_SUPR_DESC
  FROM
(SELECT * FROM zSTANCSPED
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PD.P_PRTCP_ID,PD.SSN_SOC_SECURE_NUM,PD.P_CSE_EXTID,
PD.BI_BIRTH_DT
FROM PARTICIPANT_DEMOGRAPHIC PD) PD
ON zSTANCSPED.CSPED_SSN = PD.SSN_SOC_SECURE_NUM
AND zSTANCSPED.CSPED_DOB = PD.BI_BIRTH_DT

LEFT JOIN (SELECT CP.CP_PRTCP_ID,CP.CP_CASE_ID,CP.CP_ROLE_CD
FROM CASE_PARTICIPANT CP
WHERE CP.CP_STAT_CD <> 'OBS') CP
ON CP.CP_PRTCP_ID = PD.P_PRTCP_ID

LEFT JOIN (SELECT C.MTH_YR,C.CAS_CASE_ACCT_SUM_ID,C.C_CASE_ID,C.C_CASE_EXTID,C.C_MNG_CNTY_FIPS_CD,C.C_CRNT_STAT_CD**************
FROM CASE_CAS C 
WHERE (C.C_CRNT_STAT_CD <> 'obs')) C
 ON CP.CP_CASE_ID = C.C_CASE_ID

LEFT JOIN (SELECT CCC.CCC_CASE_ID,CC.CC_COURT_CASE_EXTID,
LA.LA_FILE_DT,LA.SO_HLTH_INSURE_ORDR_CD, CC_COURT_CASE_ID,LA_COURT_CASE_ID,LA.LA_LEGL_ACTV_ID
         FROM CASE_COURT_CASE CCC
         JOIN COURT_CASE AS CC
         ON CC.CC_COURT_CASE_ID =
         CCC.CCC_COURT_CASE_ID
         JOIN LEGAL_ACTIVITY AS LA
         ON LA.LA_COURT_CASE_ID =
         CC.CC_COURT_CASE_ID AND LA.LA_LGL_ACTV_TYPE_CD = 'SUP'
         AND LA.LA_STAT_CD = 'ACT'
         ) AS LA
         ON LA.CCC_CASE_ID = C.C_CASE_ID ) zSTANCSPED1

JOIN SUPPRESSION SUP
ON zSTANCSPED1.C_CASE_ID = SUP.S_CASE_ID

UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 
  zSTANCSPED1.CSPED_LAST_NM,
  zSTANCSPED1.CSPED_FIRST_NM,
  zSTANCSPED1.CSPED_MIDDLE_NM,
  zSTANCSPED1.CSPED_SSN,
  zSTANCSPED1.CSPED_DOB,
  zSTANCSPED1.CSPED_STUDY_ID,
  zSTANCSPED1.CSPED_RA_DATE,
  zSTANCSPED1.P_CSE_EXTID,
  zSTANCSPED1.C_CASE_EXTID,
  zSTANCSPED1.CC_COURT_CASE_EXTID,
  SUP.S_ACTV_NM_CD,
  SUP.S_TYPE_CD,
  SUP.S_SUPR_LVL,
  C.C_CRNT_STAT_CD,***************

  CASE WHEN (SUP.S_STRT_TS LIKE '%1900%') OR  (SUP.S_STRT_TS LIKE '%1901%')
  THEN NULL
  ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, SUP.S_STRT_TS, 108)
  END AS 'S_STRT_TS',
  SUP.S_END_TS,
  SUP.S_SUPR_DESC
FROM
(SELECT * FROM zSTANCSPED
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PD.P_PRTCP_ID,PD.SSN_SOC_SECURE_NUM,PD.P_CSE_EXTID,
PD.BI_BIRTH_DT
FROM PARTICIPANT_DEMOGRAPHIC PD) PD
ON zSTANCSPED.CSPED_SSN = PD.SSN_SOC_SECURE_NUM
AND zSTANCSPED.CSPED_DOB = PD.BI_BIRTH_DT

LEFT JOIN (SELECT CP.CP_PRTCP_ID,CP.CP_CASE_ID,CP.CP_ROLE_CD
FROM CASE_PARTICIPANT CP
WHERE CP.CP_STAT_CD <> 'OBS') CP
ON CP.CP_PRTCP_ID = PD.P_PRTCP_ID

LEFT JOIN (SELECT C.MTH_YR,C.CAS_CASE_ACCT_SUM_ID,C.C_CASE_ID,C.C_CASE_EXTID,C.C_MNG_CNTY_FIPS_CD,C.C_CRNT_STAT_CD*************
FROM CASE_CAS C 
WHERE (C.C_CRNT_STAT_CD <> 'obs')) C
 ON CP.CP_CASE_ID = C.C_CASE_ID

LEFT JOIN (SELECT CCC.CCC_CASE_ID,CC.CC_COURT_CASE_EXTID,
LA.LA_FILE_DT,LA.SO_HLTH_INSURE_ORDR_CD, CC_COURT_CASE_ID,LA_COURT_CASE_ID,LA.LA_LEGL_ACTV_ID
         FROM CASE_COURT_CASE CCC
         JOIN COURT_CASE AS CC
         ON CC.CC_COURT_CASE_ID =
         CCC.CCC_COURT_CASE_ID
         JOIN LEGAL_ACTIVITY AS LA
         ON LA.LA_COURT_CASE_ID =
         CC.CC_COURT_CASE_ID AND LA.LA_LGL_ACTV_TYPE_CD = 'SUP'
         AND LA.LA_STAT_CD = 'ACT'
         ) AS LA
         ON LA.CCC_CASE_ID = C.C_CASE_ID ) zSTANCSPED1

JOIN SUPPRESSION SUP 
ON  zSTANCSPED1.LA_COURT_CASE_ID = SUP.S_COURT_CASE_ID
```

Comment: Just for the sake of asking you are sure C_CRNT_STAT_CD column is there in CASE_CAS table?

Comment: Can you run this inner query, `SELECT C.MTH_YR,C.CAS_CASE_ACCT_SUM_ID,C.C_CASE_ID,C.C_CASE_EXTID,C.C_MNG_CNTY_FIPS_CD,C.C_CRNT_STAT_CD*************
FROM CASE_CAS C 
WHERE (C.C_CRNT_STAT_CD <> 'obs')`? Just want to make sure the column you added exists in table `CASE_CAS`.

Answer (score 2):

The alias C is part of your subquery.  This might help show the structure:

```
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    .
    .
    .
        LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            C.MTH_YR, 
            C.CAS_CASE_ACCT_SUM_ID, 
            C.C_CASE_ID, 
            C.C_CASE_EXTID, 
            C.C_MNG_CNTY_FIPS_CD, 
            C.C_CRNT_STAT_CD --*************
        FROM CASE_CAS AS C
        WHERE(C.C_CRNT_STAT_CD <> 'obs')
    ) AS C ON CP.CP_CASE_ID = C.C_CASE_ID
        LEFT JOIN
    .
    .
    .
) AS zSTANCSPED1
    JOIN SUPPRESSION AS SUP ON zSTANCSPED1.CP_PRTCP_ID = SUP.S_PRTCP_ID
    .
    .
    .
```

The subquery named zSTANCSPED1 has SELECT *, so it looks like you should be able to just replace the C. with zSTANCSPED1.

It is beyond what you asked, but I would suggest avoiding SELECT * and explicitly listing the columns that you need.

Comment: Don't forget to apply the change for all union queries.

Comment: Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

ohh come on.. this was simple. In the top select query it needs to be zSTANCSPED1.C_CRNT_STAT_CD

Comment: I apologize for the stupid question. I thought C.C_CRNT_STAT_CD had to be in the ZSTANCSPED table and it is not. Thank you.